# How to predict on a single data sample when preprocssing is needed

Tags: machine-learning, scale

When I read scikit learn example, a typical machine learning flow is prepocessing --> learning --> predicting. As the code snippet shown below:

```
steps = [('scalar', StandardScalar()), 
     ('knn', KNeighborsClassifier())]

pipeline = Pipeline(steps)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

knn_scaled = pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = pipeline.predict(X_test)
```

Here, both training and testing dataset are scaled before fitting into the classifier. But in my task, I am going to predict on a single data sample. After training my model, I will get data from a streaming line. So each time, a single new data is received, I need to use the classifier to predict on it, and preceed my task with the predicted value.

So with only one example available each time, how to preprocess it before predicting? Scaling on this single example seems make no sense. How should I deal with such issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just as you train your classifier and use the generated model to predict the individual records, preprocessing step generates a preprocessing model as well. Let's say your input is Xi and you fitted the preprocessing and classifier models(`scaler` and `clf` respectively) already:

```
Xi_new=scaler.transform(Xi) 
print(clf.predict(Xi_new))
```

Comment: That makes sense!  Thanks for helping.